# Writing Excel file jdbctemplate

Tags: java, sql, excel, jdbctemplate

This may seem a trivial question but I am using jdbctemplate and need to export data to an excel file. Not sure if I can use the CSVWriter since jdbctemplate does not have a method to return a resultset and I need the headers. I do not want to hardcode the headers in the code either as they will change. I just want to dump the data as is from the db (along with headers).

Answer (score 0):

To access the metadata of a ResultSet you can use [RowMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html), [RowCallbackHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowCallbackHandler.html) or [ResultSetExtractor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html). To write a file for Excel you can use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/). Example:

```
Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("sheetname");
jdbcTemplate.query("select * from xyz", new RowCallbackHandler() {
    public void processRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        String columnName = rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(column);
        String columnValue = rs.getString(column);

        Row row = sheet.createRow(sheetRow);
        row.createCell(column).setCellValue(columnValue);
    }
});

try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("export.xlsx"))) {
    workbook.write(out);
}
```

Check also the implementing classes of these interfaces.